# spring new arrayList injection

Tags: spring

how can i inject an empty (new) arraylist of  "double/string/object" in spring ?

```
public class Pack{
   private List<String> names;
   private List<Course> courses;
   private List<double> prices;
   private int comp;
 }
```

xml file

```
 <bean id="pack" class="com.classes.Pack">
    <property name="compt" value="0" />
    <property name="courses" ref="courses" />
    <property name="prices" ref="prices" />
    <property name="names" ref="names" />
</bean>
```

Comment: What's that language where you can add xml code directly under Java code?

Comment: No it's two files , sorry ^^

Comment: Do you think you really need spring for creating blank lists, can't you leverage default constructor for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject an empty list like this, however this is probably unnecessary, unless you're trying to setup an example template spring XML config perhaps.

```
<property name="courses">
   <list></list>
</property>
```